# Alternative to the "switch" Statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I do not want to use Switch in my code, so I'm looking for some alternative

**Example with Switch:**

```
function write(what) {

  switch(what) {

    case 'Blue':
      alert ('Blue');
    break;

    ...

    case 'Red':
      alert ('Red');
    break;

  }

}
```

**Example without Switch:**

```
colors = [];

colors['Blue'] = function() { alert('Blue'); };
colors['Red'] = function() { alert('Red'); };


function write(what) {

  colors[what]();

}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Do you know any other alternatives?
2. Is this best solution?

Comment: It's great. Leave it.

Comment: yes, that's better solution with lesser code :)

Comment: Its also cleaner, easier to read and possible could remove duplicative code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have only a note about your second approach, you [shouldn't use an Array](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) to store non-numeric indexes (that you would call in other languages an *associative array*).

You should use a simple Object.

Also, you might want to check if the `what` argument passed to your `write` function exists as a property of your `colors` object and see if it's a function, so you can invoke it without having run-time errors:

```
var colors = {};

colors['Blue'] = function() { alert('Blue'); };
colors['Red'] = function() { alert('Red'); };


function write(what) {
  if (typeof colors[what] == 'function') {
    colors[what]();
    return;
  }
  // not a function, default case
  // ...
}
```

Comment: With respect, I think the article you linked got it wrong. Rather, one shouldn't use for..in to iterate an array.

Comment: @machine: That article also speaks about the `for...in` statement and the problems that come when the prototype member of built-in constructors like `Array` and `Object` is extended, but the bottom line of the article is that *JavaScript arrays are meant to be numeric*, and they are often used to store arbitrary key/value pairs which is bad practice...

Comment: Bottom line? Using expando properties on an array doesn't change that fact. There's nothing to gain by turning one of most versatile objects at your disposal into the least versatile. I'm not sure why you say "The article also speaks"...  My understanding is that the entire point of the article is to 'better' support use of for..in with Arrays.

Answer (score 19):

I used a structure like this today:

```
var chosenColor = 'red';

var colorString = {
    'red': 'The color is red.',
    'green': 'The color is green.',
    'blue': 'The color is blue.',
}[chosenColor] || 'The color is unknown.';
```

I like that it's a really small amount of code to choose a string based on choice.

You could also pass it to a function:

```
alert({
    'red': 'The color is red.',
    'green': 'The color is green.',
    'blue': 'The color is blue.',
}[chosenColor] || 'The color is unknown.');
```

Comment: short and simple, like it. +1

Comment: this is cool as long as the chosenColor exists in colorString. if chosenColor is 'orange' for example, you'll get a Type Error.

Comment: In fact, you could easily add a default option with

 `({'red': 'the color is red'})[chosenColor] || 'default'`

Comment: Thanks @superzamp, I have edited my code to add the default option.

Comment: Use `??` instead of `||` in 2021.

Answer (score 3):

You could use object literals, and try catch to trap the default:

```
function write(what) {
    var colors = {
    'Blue': function(){ alert('Light-Blue'); },
    'Red': function(){ alert('Deep-Red'); },
    'Green': function(){ alert('Deep-Green'); }
    }
    try {colors[what]();}
    catch(err) {colors['Green']();}//default behaviour
}
write('Pink');
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 2:

Generally, if you can replace custom control structures with a dictionary lookup, you're perfectly fine. It's easy to read and highly elegant -- stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do do a compare for a group sort of object props for a list and did not want to do a switch/case for all the possibilities so I did an array of objects assignment to a numeric rank first so the case became a simple compare. This is only 4 possibilities  but you get the drift of how to extend this to situation where a switch/case becomes unmanageable:

function mySort2(item1,item2){

```
     var matrix = {  
    'repair': 4,  
    'r/r': 3,  
    'part': 2,  
    'misc': 1  
  };  

(matrix[item1.category] < matrix[item2.category]) ? return +1 : return -1;
```

// if possible bad data need to check for this first ???

```
i1=matrix[item1.category] || null;
i2=matrix[item2.category] || null;

if (i1==null){
    // handle bad data in item 1
    return +1; // put it after 2
}

if (i2==null){
    // ditto 
    return -1; //put 1 first
}

if (i1<i2) 
    return +1;
else 
    return -1;
```

}

Comment: Its an answer: an alternative to using a switch/case for this purpose. You could also use an [] of [] to have an actual matrix of values to return.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there already. If possible you might want to add a helper function to make the setup easier. For Example:

```
function setup(what)
{
    colors[what] = function() { alert(what); };
}
```

**EDIT:**
If what you want to do for each option is more complicated clearly this will not work. As mentioned in the comments by @roe this uses the global colors which is often frowned upon.

Comment: This only works for this particular example, chances are they don't have that much in common in reality. Also colors is a global here, which is rarely a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use Dictionaries, so you could see the type of the function return, I think it's clean and scalable, although it's just pure JS.

```
const ColorDictionary = {
  red: 'applies red color',
  blue: ' applies blue color',
  green: 'applies green color',
}

const useShowColors = (color) => {

 // color will be selected or fallout to default value.
 const getColor = () => (
  ColorDicionary[color] ?? 'applies default color' 
 )
 
 return { getColor }
}

const { getColor } = useShowColors() //pass the color you wish.
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to define a class with a `write` method, and override that in subclasses `Red` and `Blue` to do the right thing.

Whether or not that is better than your proposed solution, depends on your particular situation.

Answer (score -1):

As I said, it's great. The only thing I can add to your solution is that it's perhaps better to localize your `colors`.

```
function write(what) {
    var colors = [];
    colors['Blue'] = function() { alert('Blue'); };
    colors['Red'] = function() { alert('Red'); };
    colors[what]();
}
```