# looking for better way than having switch statement in array.map for javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

looking for better way than having switch statement in array.map for javascript. Basically is there a better way to change all the values in an array given an object or something?
In this case i want to abbreviate or change all the values of an array to different values given. should i use another map or another object? Javascript Es6 question
I have this:

```
const abvDepartments = departments.map(equip => {
  switch (equip) {
    case 'service':
      return 'Svc';
      break;
    case 'help':
      return 'HLP';
      break;
    case 'contracts':
      return 'Con';
      break;
    default:
      return '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to `break` after a `return`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative to the "switch" Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307157/alternative-to-the-switch-statement)

Answer (score 3):

There's many possibilities here, but one option would be something like this:

```js
const abvDepartments = departments.map(equip => {
  return {
    'service': 'Svc',
    'help': 'HLP',
    'contracts': 'Con'
  }[equip] || '';
});
```

If you'd like, and you're not doing anything else in the map, you can shorten that even further:

```js
const abvDepartments = departments.map(equip => ({
  'service': 'Svc',
  'help': 'HLP',
  'contracts': 'Con'
}[equip] || ''));
```

Comment: `|| ''`, for the default.

Comment: +1 for this. 

one more thing I would suggest here. as an object is  a constant therefore make it const outside the method and use it inside

const depCode = {
  'service': 'Svc',
  'help': 'HLP',
  'contracts': 'Con'
}

const abvDepartments = departments.map(equip => depCode[equip] || '' );

Answer (score 3):

You can keep an object like below:

`const options = {'service':'Svc','help': 'HLP' }`

and then :

```
const abvDepartments = departments.map(equip => options[equip] || "");
```

Answer (score 0):

declare constants outside your logic and that will always be neat. Happy Coding :)

```
// declare constants with uppercase
const DEP_CODE = {
  'service': 'Svc',
  'help': 'HLP',
  'contracts': 'Con'
}

const abvDepartments = departments.map(equip => DEP_CODE[equip] || '' );
```